# etcdctl: unknown command "save" for "etcdctl"

Tags: kubernetes, etcd, etcdctl

I entered the etcd container:

```
kubectl -n kube-system exec -it etcd-k8scp -- sh
```

The I try to backup the container like explained in the [K8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-upgrade-etcd/#built-in-snapshot)

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints $ENDPOINT snapshot save snapshotdb
```

I get this error:

> Error: unknown command "save" for "etcdctl"

What's wrong with my command?

Comment: Dear Stackoverflow-Police please tell Kubernetes.io to link to Serverfault and not Stackoverflow, if you want to redirect the traffic to that site. Then I will create answers there.

Answer (score 3):

I forgot to set `$ENDPOINT`.

If it is empty, then etcdctl gets this:

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints snapshot save snapshotdb
```

etcdctl thinks I want to address the endpoint called "snapshot" and execute the command "save"

:-)