# Error doing a snapshot using etcdctl options in Kubernetes

Tags: linux, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, etcd

I have setup a kubernetes cluster with 2 `master` nodes and 4 `worker nodes`, I am trying to do an etcd backup
as described in the documentation inside my etcd container.

```
‍ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=https://127.0.0.1:2379 \
  --cacert=<trusted-ca-file> --cert=<cert-file> --key=<key-file> \
  snapshot save <backup-file-location>
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error: unknown command "save" for "etcdctl"
```

Are there something to concider upfront?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first if this is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70906419/6309)

> I forgot to set `$ENDPOINT`.

That can happen if the `--endpoints` flag is not correctly followed by an actual endpoint.
In your case, because of the lack of a specified endpoint after the `--endpoints` flag, `etcdctl` is interpreting "`snapshot`" as the endpoint, and "`save`" as the command - which could result in the error you are seeing.

A better formed command would be:

```bash
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=https://127.0.0.1:2379 \
  --cacert=<trusted-ca-file> --cert=<cert-file> --key=<key-file> \
  snapshot save <backup-file-location>
```

Do replace `<trusted-ca-file>`, `<cert-file>`, `<key-file>`, and `<backup-file-location>` with your actual file paths.

The `--endpoints` flag specifies the endpoint to connect to your etcd server. In a Kubernetes cluster, you typically connect to the etcd server through localhost (127.0.0.1) on port 2379, which is the default etcd client port.

---

Also, just in case, in some shells, using the `\` character for line continuation might cause issues, try running the command all on one line:

`ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=https://127.0.0.1:2379 --cacert=<trusted-ca-file> --cert=<cert-file> --key=<key-file> snapshot save <backup-file-location>`

Another issue might be that the `<backup-file-location>` you are specifying does not exist or the `etcdctl` does not have permission to write to it. Make sure the directory you are trying to save the snapshot to exists and that the user running the `etcdctl` command has permission to write to it.

Comment: Hey yes sorry I pasted the real path of the TLS related files. It was just an example. Let me check out the endpoint

Comment: Ahh sorry forgot to update. The Endpoint seems also correct.

Comment: @pwoltschk OK, I have edited the answer to add some suggestions

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like you have a version mismatch between your client and the API.

You can run `etcdctl version` to see what version you're using and make sure the client doesn't use an obsolete version.

More details [here](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.4/dev-guide/interacting_v3/#find-versions).

Comment: etcdctl version: 3.4.26 
API version: 3.4 this seems okay

Answer (score 0):

etcdctl tries to run the command `save`, like `etcdctl save <backup-file-location>` and since there is no `save` command, you get the error.

I'm guessing you're using environment variables. Check if those are set, otherwise the arguments are shifted and etcdctl tries to execute the command `save` instead of `snapshot save`, like:

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl 
  --endpoints $ENDPOINT \
  --cacert $CA \
  --cert $CRT \
  --key $KEY \
  snapshot save <backup-file-location>
```

becomes

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl 
  --endpoints <some-url> \
  --cacert <some-path> 
  --cert <some-path> \ 
  --key snapshot \
  save <backup-file-location>
```